# Figure in Header

Tags: graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr

For our documentation I am trying to put an image inside the header via  but it won't work. I already have tried multiple codes but I can't solve my problem with `fancyhdr`. Anybody has an idea?

This is the original sty sheet:

```
%%
%% This style is derived from the docbook one.
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{asciidoc}[2008/06/05 AsciiDoc DocBook Style]

\RequirePackageWithOptions{docbook}

\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
}{
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\linespread{1.3}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\def\DBKcover{
\ifthenelse{\equal{\DBKedition}{}}{\def\edhead{}}{\def\edhead{Ed. \DBKedition}}

% interligne double
\setlength{\oldbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2\oldbaselineskip}

\sffamily

%%\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{../../images/sipwise-logo}\\[1cm]\hspace*{3cm}
\hfill\includegraphics{../../images/sipwise-logo}\hspace*{1cm}

\definecolor{SipwiseGreen}{HTML}{006600}
\definecolor{SipwiseGray}{HTML}{000000}

% not available with LaTeX as provided with >= Debian/wheezy any longer ootb
\@ifundefined{White}{
  \definecolor{White}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
}{}

\vspace*{9cm}
\hspace*{-3cm}\colorbox{SipwiseGreen}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][1.3cm][t]{1.3\textwidth}
    \color{SipwiseGreen}
    \hspace*{3cm}\hfill Sipwise GmbH\hspace*{3cm}
  \end{minipage}
}
\linebreak[4]
\hspace*{-3cm}\colorbox{SipwiseGray}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][6cm][t]{1.3\textwidth}
    \color{White}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \hspace*{3cm}\hfill\Huge\DBKtitle\hspace*{3cm}\\
    \vfill
    \hspace*{3cm}\hfill\Large Sipwise GmbH\hspace*{3cm}\\
    \ttfamily\hspace*{3cm}\hfill\large <support@sipwise.com>\hspace*{3cm}\\
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\clearpage
\sffamily

% Format for the other pages
\newpage
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\oldbaselineskip}

% dblatex 0.3-2   (Debian/squeeze) provides DBKcheadfront,
% dblatex 0.3.4-1 (Debian/wheezy) no longer provides DBKcheadfront
\@ifundefined{DBKcheadfront}{
  \chead[]{}
}{
  \chead[]{\DBKcheadfront}
}

\lfoot[]{}
}

\fancyhf{}

\rhead{\rightmark}
\rfoot{\thepage}

% For DocBook literallayout elements, see `./dblatex/dblatex-readme.txt`.
\usepackage{alltt}
```

This is my transformed version:

```
%%
%% This style is derived from the docbook one.
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{asciidoc}[2008/06/05 AsciiDoc DocBook Style]

\RequirePackageWithOptions{docbook}

\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames, fancyhdr}{xcolor}
}{
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames, fancyhdr]{xcolor}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\linespread{1.3}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\def\DBKcover{
\ifthenelse{\equal{\DBKedition}{}}{\def\edhead{}}{\def\edhead{Ed. \DBKedition}}

% interligne double
\setlength{\oldbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2\oldbaselineskip}

\sffamily

%%\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{../../images/sipwise-logo}\\[1cm]\hspace*{3cm}
\hfill\includegraphics{../../images/sipwise-logo}\hspace*{1cm}

\definecolor{SipwiseGreen}{HTML}{006600}
\definecolor{SipwiseGray}{HTML}{000000}

% not available with LaTeX as provided with >= Debian/wheezy any longer ootb
\@ifundefined{White}{
  \definecolor{White}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
}{}

\vspace*{9cm}
\hspace*{-3cm}\colorbox{SipwiseGreen}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][1.3cm][t]{1.3\textwidth}
    \color{SipwiseGreen}
    \hspace*{3cm}\hfill Sipwise GmbH\hspace*{3cm}
  \end{minipage}
}
\linebreak[4]
\hspace*{-3cm}\colorbox{SipwiseGray}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][6cm][t]{1.3\textwidth}
    \color{White}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \hspace*{3cm}\hfill\Huge\DBKtitle\hspace*{3cm}\\
    \vfill
    \hspace*{3cm}\hfill\Large Sipwise GmbH\hspace*{3cm}\\
    \ttfamily\hspace*{3cm}\hfill\large <support@sipwise.com>\hspace*{3cm}\\
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\clearpage
\sffamily

% Format for the other pages
\newpage
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\oldbaselineskip}

% dblatex 0.3-2   (Debian/squeeze) provides DBKcheadfront,
% dblatex 0.3.4-1 (Debian/wheezy) no longer provides DBKcheadfront
\@ifundefined{DBKcheadfront}{
  \chead[]{}
}{
  \chead[]{\DBKcheadfront}
}

\lfoot[]{}
}

\fancyhdr{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{
\includegraphics{logo_header.png}}


\rfoot{\thepage}

% For DocBook literallayout elements, see `./dblatex/dblatex-readme.txt`.
\usepackage{alltt}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: i removed the float tag since you have no float enviornemnt arround your picture

Comment: For better help sooner make it a complete mwe (include a base document using you style and showing the error).

Answer (score 3):

Try this: (it is an example for a dcoument, not a style file)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\begin{picture}(0,0)
{\includegraphics[height=0.6cm,width=0.6cm]{images/logo.png}}
\end{picture}}
\rhead{\sf{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

from the fancyhdr manual:

> In order not to disturb the normal header layout we put the text in a
>   zero-sized picture . Generally this is the best way to position things
>   on fixed places on the page. You can then also use the normal
>   headings. See also section 21 for another example of this technique

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but it still won't work. I've already tried similar commands. I was also thinking that maybe one of the other commands is overwriting this one? It is really frustrating!

Comment: do you actually see other parts of fancyhdr showing up? (Is the image the problem or is the problem that the fancyhdr style is applied to no pages at all?)

Comment: The image is the problem. It still shows me the title of the document but not the logo. Setting the page number in the footer for example is no problem.

Comment: @Tulip: I do not see a requirePackage command for `graphicx`, also try loading the graphics package with the `demo` option and give dimensions, to ensure you are not loading a white image or it is scaled to small. Do you get any warnings or errors?